# Laravel - Assign Middleware to specific method with specific request method in controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, middleware

I use Laravel 5.6.

I need to assign TWO DIFFERENT middleware in a controller with a same method but different REQUEST method (post and put).

I know it can be assigned in `route/web.php`.

But I just wondering is there any way to solve this issue in ONLY CONTROLLER?

This is the code below

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Users;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\AuthPagesController;

class Users extends AuthPagesController
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        //this middleware should be for POST request
        $this->middleware('permission:User -> Add Item')->only('save'); 

        //this middleware should be for PUT request
        $this->middleware('permission:User -> Update Item')->only('save'); 
    }

    public function save(Request $req, $id=null){

        if ($req->isMethod('post')){

             //only check for middleware 'permission:User -> Add Item'
             //then run the 'Add Item' code

        }elseif($req->isMethod('put')){

             //only check for middleware 'permission:User -> Update Item'
             //then run the 'Update Item' code

        }

    }
}
```

But the code above will create problem for me because it will check BOTH MIDDLEWARE.

Comment: try `request()->method()`

Comment: I would highly recommend against authorization in a middleware.   You're going to have a variety of problems when you try to get more granular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha. I just solved my own problem.

Actually it is very simple. Just do like this in `__construct` method.

```
public function __construct(Request $req)
{
    //this middleware should be for POST request only
    if($req->isMethod('post')){
        $this->middleware('permission:User -> Add Item')->only('save'); 
    }

    //this middleware should be for PUT request only
    if($req->isMethod('put')){
        $this->middleware('permission:User -> Update Item')->only('save'); 
    }
}

public function save(Request $req, $id=null){

    // for security purpose, allow only 'post' and 'put' request
    if(!$req->isMethod('post') && !$req->isMethod('put')) return false;

    if ($req->isMethod('post')){

         //only check for middleware 'permission:User -> Add Item'
         //then run the 'Add Item' code

    }elseif($req->isMethod('put')){

         //only check for middleware 'permission:User -> Update Item'
         //then run the 'Update Item' code

    }

}
```

I hope this answer will be helpful to others. :D